# Accessing objects and variables from swf across domains

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, cross-domain-policy, asunit

I am trying to access a variable from a `test.swf` on b.com from a `parent.swf` on a.com.

test.swf:

```
Security.allowDomain("a.com");
var test = 0;
```

parent.swf:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var url:String = "http://b.com/test.swf";
loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
```

I can access the swf like this. But how can I access and change the `var test` in test.swf?

Answer (score 0):

Basically can do so by modifying the url of the swf you are loading in.

[Check this out](http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2009/02/passing-parameters-to-loaded-swf.html)